# How to run google chrome as root in linux

Tags: root, chrome, privileges

when I want to run google chrome as root, an error message with this title appears:

> Google chrome can not be run as root

and the body of message is:

> to run as root, you must specify an alternate --user-data-dir for
>   storage of profile information.

can anyone help me?

Comment: although it's not a good work to run this application as root, I'll explain the method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To run google chrome as root, follow these steps:

1. Open `google-chrome` in your favorite editor (replacing `$EDITOR` with your favorite):

   ```
   $EDITOR $(which google-chrome)
   ```
2. Add `--user-data-dir` at the very end of the file.

   my file looks like this:

   ```
   exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$PROFILE_DIRECTORY_FLAG" \   "$@"
   --user-data-dir
   ```
3. Save and close the editor.

you’re done. Enjoy it :)

---

if you want to see video tutorial, you can check my blog post:

[How to run google chrome as root in Linux - MoeinFatehi](http://blog.moeinfatehi.ir/how-to-run-google-chrome-as-root-in-linux/)

Comment: Just to be clear, the correct answer here is “You don't.” Running graphical apps as root really isn't a great idea.

Comment: well I have heard you should not run graphical applications as root and I decided I'd do it just to find out why not. I planned to do it till I found out. This is now 14 years ago.

Comment: You should read up on the principal of least privilege.

Comment: I ended up having to use `--no-sandbox` as well. yolo

Answer (score 4):

Now you cannot run google-chrome as root user on updated versions, To run Google Chrome as standard user (while Logged in as Root)

open terminal and type:

`adduser -u chromeuser` OR `useradd -m chromeuser`

To run google chrome use command:

`gksu -u chromeuser google-chrome` OR `sux chromeuser google-chrome`

If you don't want to run it from Terminal then add chrome in taskbar and then right-click on it, select properties and add the above command in the command parameter.

Comment: also using an existing user account worked for me : `gksu -u gv google-chrome-stable`. Though i received some erros in terminal, but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

For those who may be still googling at Dec 2016 - Google Chrome Version 54.0.2840.90 64bit under XFCE and Debian 8.5:

Case 1: Chrome not starting at all
In my setup just by running in terminal `google-chrome-stable` i was getting immediately an error in terminal `illegal instruction`. No frames, no screen blanking , no black windows. Just a rude console error. 
This error goes away by using the `--no-sandbox` command line option.

Case 2: Chrome still refuses to open even with --no-sandbox option
That was not my case since --no-sandbox was enough, but if you experience such behavior you could try to disable everything when calling chrome, like:

```
google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu --disable-extensions --disable-d3d11 --disable-local-storage --disable-notifications --disable-offne-pages --disable-plugin-power-saver --disable-plugins-discovery --disable-sync --disable-translate --disable-webgl --no-experiments --no-sandbox
```

Then you can step by step enable options till to identify which one breaks.
PS: All CLI flags/args can be found [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Case 3: Message `Please start Google Chrome as a normal user.To run as root you must specify an alternate --user-data-dir for storage of profile information` appears.

Solution that worked for me :
Go to `/opt/google/chrome` and open file `google-chrome` which is actually a bash script.

At the end of the script find the part

```
if [[ -n "$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" ]]; then
  # Note: exec -a below is a bashism.
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  \
    --user-data-dir="$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" "$@"
else
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"
fi
```

And change the else part like this:

```
else
  #exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir="$HOME"
fi
```

Save, and run `google-chrome-stable --no-sandbox` .
I got up and surfing.

For a more sophisticated solution i personally applied a kind of user check to avoid possible disturbance running chrome as normal user :

```
else
    if [ "$USER" = "root" ]  || [ "$LOGNAME" = "root" ];then 
        exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir="$HOME"
    else
        exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"
    fi
```

Another Workaround:
You can not modify the google-chrome file as indicated above, and you can either follow recomendation of @tzafar for creating a new user or to launch chrome using an existing normal user account : `gksu -u user google-chrome-stable` (this worked but some error messages received in terminal).

Comment: worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

run the folloing command and open google-chrome it will works

```
sed -i -e 's@Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U@Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox@g' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

To run google chrome as root, add this parameter "--no-sandbox"

[image]

it will works for me.

Comment: What are the actual consequences of doing this?

Comment: Are the same as the consequences of using a root account

Answer (score 0):

You can run chrome as root by `un-sandboxing` it.

I made a simple script that can help enable or disable different browsers in root. The script will present you a menu which will enable or disable a browser based on your selection.

[**Github repo link**](https://github.com/david-kariuki/linux-unsandbox-browsers-cli)

[Profile link](https://github.com/david-kariuki/)

Use the profile link incase the repo link wount work.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

i have try all the solution provided there so by my opinion this one is the best.

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user_name/.config/google-chrome

just run command you dont need to do anything.

Comment: Hello Abhinav. Could you [please explain](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/520874/edit) how this answers the question of running Chrome as root.

Answer (score -2):

this is a long shot but try this

> sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user_name/.config/google-chrome

dont need to configure sandbox anymore

Comment: How would making all the Chrome config readable by everyone help?

Comment: problem is different every time if 'google-chrome --no-sandbox' don't work,usually sudo is required cause it don't have enough permission of the /home/usr_name/.config/google-chrome folder or some other directories.

Comment: Note that root is not restricted by file permissions or file ownerships.